# Converting To MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working to convert to MYSQLi. something i'm not entirely confident in just yet. I'm getting an error trying to breakdown this portion of my script.

```
 <?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $level = ($_POST['level']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
    include "includes/db_conx.php"; 

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $productMatch = mysqli_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

    if ($productMatch > 0) {
       header("location: message.php?msg=usererror");
       exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['username']);
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $p_hash = md5($password);
    $sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO users (username, password, ip, email, level, date_added) 
        VALUES('$username','$p_hash','$ip','$email','$level',now())") or die (mysql_error());
    header("location: order_complete.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
```

I believe I've got most of it down, but the second half of this is giving me fits. I'm trying to establish past

> // Add this product into the database now

a mysqli conversion. I just can't seem to keep myself from mangling the script and throwing all kinds of errors. I believe I'm about half way there, but introducing select is throwing me off. Can someone help me to figure out this.

Comment: What is the value of $level? Its not assigned in this code. Also, please mention the error message in this.

Comment: I've updated the script to show all. Normally i've been told its better to only include the portion that contains the problem. Sorry.

Comment: This si the error

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in /home/learnsi/public_html/user-info.php on line 21 Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/learnsi/public_html/user-info.php on line 31 Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/learnsi/public_html/user-info.php on line 34 Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /home/learnsi/public_html/user-info.php on line 34

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the $sql as a param to mysqli_num_rows() and it should be the result of a mysqli_query().

So change to this.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$productMatch = mysqli_num_rows($user_query); // count the output amount
```

A better name for that variable might be $user_result or something with the word result in.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below mentioned code.

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {    

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $level = ($_POST['level']);
    // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
     include "includes/db_conx.php"; // I guess it has $db_conx =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $productMatch = mysqli_num_rows($user_query); // count the output amount

    if ($productMatch > 0) {

           header("location: message.php?msg=usererror");
        exit();
    }
    // Add this product into the database now
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['username']);
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['email']);

    $p_hash = md5($password);

$sql = mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO users (username, password, ip, email, level, date_added) VALUES('$username','$p_hash','$ip','$email','$level',now())") or die (mysqli_error($db_conx));

    header("location: order_complete.php"); 
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean @debashis

Comment: I edited this code. Check and use. Basically, you were not using the mysql connection details as parameter while using , mysqli_* function.

Comment: I was confused a bit, but I think I knw what you mean. I'm getting the error

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/learnsi/public_html/user-info.php:7) in /home/learnsi/public_html/user-info.php on line 23

Comment: Are you getting the warning after trying the above code (i did modification. please check carefully)? Use ob_start() at the top of the php page to remove the warning.

Comment: yes I'm still getting this warning. With the addition of ob_start I'm getting a blank screen. This error is saying that in fact a match has been found, but then it doesn't run to the message.php

Comment: I just got it using by putting the ob_start() within its own <?php ?>

Can I ask what exactly we are doing here? Is this a "hack"(loosely used here)? If it is. Is there a way to go around "hacking" it?